# LazyInit Exception when Refreshing a page on Alfresco 3 (Hibernate 3 + Spring)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, alfresco

I got the following issue on the specific layer we have on Alfresco (version 3, using hibernate 3 + spring):

When a page is first loaded, everything goes fine. No problem.

When we do an interaction on this page that leads to a refresh, we have some 
`lazyinitializationexception could not initialize proxy - no session`.

I know the lazyinit is a common issue. But because of the fact that we want only make changes on the specific layer not on the alfresco layer, many resolutions can't be applied.

The one consisting in forcing the sessions to stay open is not possible for us.

The one using `Hibernate.Initialize` leads to this error:

```
User:admin ERROR [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException] failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.jbpm.taskmgmt.exe.TaskInstance.variableInstances, no session or session was closed
```

So I got three questions:

1. Does someone has an idea of why on the first load, we have no problem and on refresh we got the lazyInit Exception ?
2. How could we make the hibernate.initialize work ?
3. Is there any other way to solve this issue ?

To say a little more about the context:
We want to show to user via IHM the task history. To do that we fill a table, to do so we collect the current taskInstance ti and the previous ones and for each of them we do a `ti.GetName()`, `ti.GetDescription()`, etc. The issue seems to come that after collecting the Task Instances, the hibernate session is close, so we can't perform `ti.GetName()` and other operations on ti.

In advance thank you all for your help,
Regards

Comment: Some code may explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of days of working on that, we just found how to solve it. A colleague just solve it when I was writing the desperate post :)

So the solution was to use

```
getHibernateTemplate().Hibernate.Initialize(ti.GetName());
```

directly in the Callback part of the DAO class.

Hope it will be useful to others and thanks for your efforts to help and I'm always unsure on whether I should post code or not to keep the post simple.